# python pyproject.toml enclose files in package dir

Tags: setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

repo package directory:

```
report:
  report.py
  template.dat
  template_testline.dat
```

and in `pyproject.toml` I have:

```
[tool.setuptools]
packages = [ "report" ]
```

but when I install the program the templatefiles are not enclosed in the package, only the report.py file:

```
ls -l /Users/mobj/.pyenv/versions/report/lib/python3.12/site-packages/report/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  3 mobj  staff     96 Dec  1 17:18 __pycache__
-rw-r--r--  1 mobj  staff  11618 Dec  1 17:18 report.py
```

How can I get them enclosed?

Comment: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html

Comment: I searched pyproject.toml not setuptools, excellent

Answer (score 0):

Seems like adding the data-files to the same directory did not work, but if I added it into a directory `dat` under the package `report` it worked:

```
[tool.setuptools]
include-package-data = true
packages = ["report"]

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
report = ["dat/*.dat"]
```

If I added `report = ["*.dat"]`and put them in the same directory they did not show up.

You can see what you module have for files with `pip show -f <modulename>`